# API returning different feeds

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am getting different results for feeds when using graph API for RealMadrid page (http://www.facebook.com/RealMadrid). The URL I am using is https://graph.facebook.com/19034719952/feed?access_token=%5BTOKEN%5D. The feeds shown in the FB page are not being returned by the above API call. I am already liking this page.

Comment: What kind of token are you using - app or user access token?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Replace your access token in "Access token: " field at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=19034719952%2Ffeed . Are you able to get the feed?

**Step 2**: If the answer from step 1 is 'no', then you need test your access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. Are you able to get the "Expires" field? If the answer is 'no', then you're using app access token and you should using User access token instead. If the answer is 'yes', tell me.

Screenshot for comment:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got reply from the bug I filed with FB. They say the design of feeds for this user is like that. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/624934034201180. The answer to your questions: #1. No, not able to get feeds #2. Yes, I am getting the expires field which is two months from now.

Comment: Actually you should attach some screenshot or plain text  as example of the different feed. So people can know the feed/post_id you're talking about. Just my opinion :)

Comment: I didn't attach because the feed is too long, more than 12,000 characters

Comment: @user1481853 I means only extract 1 to 2 feeds which are not being returned by the above API call, not all feeds.

Comment: "id": "19034719952_10150410420634953",
         "from": {
            "name": "Rizal Atlanta",
            "id": "100000539375709"
         },
         "to": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "19034719952",
                  "category": "Professional sports team",
                  "name": "Real Madrid C.F."
               }
            ]
         },
         "message": "Good real madrid, . . .",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link":
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",

Comment: @user1481853 Take a look on my screenshot, i have no problem to get the feed.